# return multiple results from SQLite in browser (HTML) query

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, search

I'm new to Flask and Python. I am creating a camping log using SQLite. I have created an html file that saves user inputs into an SQLite database. The user can recall 1 entry "row" based on 2 different parameters (month and/or location). I want to be able to recall all entry's that satisfy parameters utilized.

To clarify, the user logs a camping trip that includes: `start_date`, `end_date`, `location`, `camping_site`, `weather`, `notes`, and `pictures`. At the bottom of the browser there is a search that will allow the user to see camping trips by month, location or both. Currently, the user only has access to the most recent entry for that month, location or both. I'm sure this is a simple fix but I have scoured the internet and have failed to find a solution to my specific predicament.

Here is the code for my Flask app:

```py
@app.route('/past-trips', methods=['GET'])
def get_past_trips(): 
    # Fetch past trip information from the database
    db = get_db()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM past_trips")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    # Convert the rows into a list of dictionaries
    past_trips = []
    for row in rows:
        trip = {
            'start_date': row['start_date'],
            'end_date': row['end_date'],
            'location': row['location'],
            'camping_site': row['camping_site'],
            'weather': row['weather'],
            'notes': row['notes'],
            'pictures': row['pictures']
        }
        past_trips.append(trip)

    # Retrieve query parameters for filtering
    location = request.args.get('location')
    month = request.args.get('month')
    
    # Filter past trips based on query parameters
    filtered_trips = past_trips  # Initialize the filtered trips list with all past trips

    if location:
        # Perform case-insensitive comparison
        location = location.lower()
        filtered_trips = [trip for trip in filtered_trips if trip['location'].lower() == location]

    if month:
        # Convert month name to YYYY-MM format
        month_names = {
            'january': '01',
            'february': '02',
            'march': '03',
            'april': '04',
            'may': '05',
            'june': '06',
            'july': '07',
            'august': '08',
            'september': '09',
            'october': '10',
            'november': '11',
            'december': '12'
        }

        if month in month_names:
            month = month_names[month]
            filtered_trips = [trip for trip in filtered_trips if
                              datetime.datetime.strptime(trip['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m') == month]

    print(filtered_trips)  # Print the filtered past trips

    # Return the filtered past trip information as a JSON response
    return jsonify(filtered_trips)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.run()
```

Pertinent camping_ui.html code

```html
   <div class="my-5">
      <h2 class="text-center mb-3">Most Recent Trip by Month or Location</h2>
      <div class="row mb-3">
        <label for="month" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Month</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select class="form-select" id="month">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="january">January</option>
            <option value="february">February</option>
            <option value="march">March</option>
            <option value="april">April</option>
            <option value="may">May</option>
            <option value="june">June</option>
            <option value="july">July</option>
            <option value="august">August</option>
            <option value="september">September</option>
            <option value="october">October</option>
            <option value="november">November</option>
            <option value="december">December</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mb-3">
        <label for="past-location" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Location</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="past-location">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="searchPastTrips()">Search</button>
      </div>
      <div class="my-5">
        <h3 class="text-center">Results</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
              <th scope="col">End Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Location</th>
              <th scope="col">Camping Site ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Weather</th>
              <th scope="col">Notes</th>
              <th scope="col">Pictures</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="past-trips">
            <!-- past trips will be populated here -->
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  // Function to fetch and display past trips based on month and location
  function searchPastTrips() {
    const monthSelect = document.getElementById('month');
    const locationInput = document.getElementById('past-location');

    const selectedMonth = monthSelect.value.toLowerCase();
    const selectedLocation = locationInput.value.toLowerCase();

    const url = `/past-trips?month=${selectedMonth}&location=${selectedLocation}`;

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const pastTripsContainer = document.getElementById('past-trips');
        pastTripsContainer.innerHTML = '';

        data.forEach(trip => {
          const row = document.createElement('tr');

          const pastTripsContainer = document.getElementById('past-trips');
          pastTripsContainer.innerHTML = '';

          const startDateCell = document.createElement('td');
          startDateCell.textContent = trip.start_date;
          row.appendChild(startDateCell);

          const endDateCell = document.createElement('td');
          endDateCell.textContent = trip.end_date;
          row.appendChild(endDateCell);

          const locationCell = document.createElement('td');
          locationCell.textContent = trip.location;
          row.appendChild(locationCell);

          const campingSiteCell = document.createElement('td');
          campingSiteCell.textContent = trip.camping_site;
          row.appendChild(campingSiteCell);

          const weatherCell = document.createElement('td');
          weatherCell.textContent = trip.weather;
          row.appendChild(weatherCell);

          const notesCell = document.createElement('td');
          notesCell.textContent = trip.notes;
          row.appendChild(notesCell);

          const picturesCell = document.createElement('td');
          const pictureImage = document.createElement('img');
          // pictureImage.src = trip.pictures; // Assuming the picture field contains the image URL
          picturesCell.appendChild(pictureImage);
          row.appendChild(picturesCell);

          pastTripsContainer.appendChild(row);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  // Call the function to fetch and display past trips when the page loads
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', searchPastTrips);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add the relevant code for your question (probably the SQL queries and how you're handling the return values on your server)

Comment: Where are the variables `month` and `month_names` coming from? Try to paint a detailed picture with your question and you code. Without all the information, it is very difficult for us to help you. Also, when you add code, add it to your actual question by using the "Edit" feature rather than posting it as a comment.

Comment: I apologize and very much appreciate your patience. I have updated the code to include the entire app.py file. In the Flask console I can see the correct list of filtered trips (multiple trips populate the console). Only 1 trip is shown in the browser.

Comment: No worries - looks like you figured it out, nice!

Answer (score 0):

pastTripsContainer was emptied within the loop

```
fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const pastTripsContainer = document.getElementById('past-trips');
        pastTripsContainer.innerHTML = '';

        data.forEach(trip => {
          const row = document.createElement('tr');

          const pastTripsContainer = document.getElementById('past-trips');
          pastTripsContainer.innerHTML = '';
```